# Dynamically assigning a property in a usercontrol in an ASP.NET repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I currently have a repeater control and inside the itemtemplate I have a usercontrol. This usercontrol renders correctly, but I am trying to assign a dataitem to a property in the repeater control.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <uc1:Request ID="Request1" runat="server" RequestId='<%# Eval("RequestId") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

RequestId is just an Int32. It just doesn't assign it.

I can put the eval outside of the usercontrol just in the itemtemplate and it correctly outputs the right id.

If I remove the whole eval and just type a number in then it works fine.

Any help appreciated.

[UPDATE] : Issue Solved

I was using an EntityDataSource and this automatically binded to the repeater. It printed out all the information from the database on the screen without any codebehind. But when I put in the code behind Repeater1.DataBind(); it then started to work.

I don't know why, but hey it's solved. It now successfully passes the value through. I imagine it has something to do with the page lifecycle.

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Shouldn't there be a closing ' right after %> ?

Comment: Nothing is working still. The RequestId just doesn't get set when I use Eval. When I do <%# Eval("RequestId") %> just above the usercontrol so just in open space it prints perfectly on the screen. If I hard code the number e.g. RequestId="2" it works fine. But it just doesn't work when done as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just bind with repeater collection of int, you need use this:

```
<uc1:Request ID="Request1" runat="server" RequestId='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
```

And don't forget to call DataBind() for repeater or for Page where there is a repeater control.

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing a `'` at the end?

change following:

```
RequestId='<%# Eval("RequestId") %> />
```

to

```
RequestId='<%# Eval("RequestId") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by using Repeater control's ItemDataBound event, so that you can set the dynamic property for the control.